# error in video input opencv 3.3.0

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

I have installed OpenCV 3.3.0 it works fine for the images but when i try to take video input it shows folowing error

```
VideoCapture failed
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 10638
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “video.py”, line 18, in
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:10638: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Here is my code for same :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if cap.isOpened() == False:
    print (“VideoCapture failed”)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow(‘frameq’,frame)
    cv2.imshow(‘frame’,gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(‘q’):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Your comment is awaiting moderation.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: `cvtColor()` expects your image to have either 3 channels (RGB) or 4 channels (RGBA). Your image appears not to comply, so is maybe already greyscale (single channel).

Comment: I would say that it is more likely that frame is empty. You need to check if read from your camera was successful before doing operations on result mat

Comment: @eyllanesc ubuntu 16.04